# How does AccountManager.KEY_INTENT looks like within TaskSample sample code

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I am refering code in [TaskSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples#126)

As I never have chance to get into the following `if` statement within **`gotAccount` method `AccountManager` callback**

```
if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
    Intent intent = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
    intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() & ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
}
```

Anyone has idea what kind of Intent will be started? Do you mind to post a **screenshot** of that Intent?

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, you might get a login activity if you don't have a cached token or a saved password.

> If a previously generated auth token is cached for this account and
>   type, then it is returned. Otherwise, if a saved password is
>   available, it is sent to the server to generate a new auth token.
>   Otherwise, an Intent is returned which, when started, will prompt the
>   user for a password. If the notifyAuthFailure parameter is set, a
>   status bar notification is also created with the same Intent, alerting
>   the user that they need to enter a password at some point.

The actual activity will depend on the account type, and you shouldn't really care how it looks like.

Comment: Do you have idea how I can get into that flow? As I keep clearing my application data cache, but I still cannot fall into that if scope.

Comment: This is not related to your app's data, accounts are kept in a system database. You might try removing your Google account, but that will probably prompt you to add one.